# merge two arrays, find duplicate key and update value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two array, where  new array locking for duplicate key in old array and replace that value with value from new array,

old array

```
 Array
(
    [tool_situs] => Array
        (
            [template] => aa
            [title] => bb

        )

 [style] => Array
        (
            [.title] => Array
                (
                    [color] => red
                    [font-size] => 20px

                )

        )

)
```

and  new array

```
 Array
(
    [tool_situs] => Array
        (
            [title] => ddd
        )

    [style] => Array
        (
            [.title] => Array
                (
                    [color] => #fff

                )

        )

)
```

I Already Tried using `array_merge_recursive()` but not replace value of duplicate key, only add new value from new array

```
 Array
(
    [tool_situs] => Array
        (
            [template] => aa
            [title] => Array
            (
                [0] => aa
                [1] => ddd
            )

        )

 [style] => Array
        (
            [.title] => Array
                (
                    [color] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => red
                        [1] => #fff
                    )
                    [font-size] => 20px

                )

        )

)
```

in array ebove, **tool_situs->title** only add new array from new array, also **style->.title->color** return by add new value from ne array.

help me how to both value of tool_situs->title and  style->.title->color  replace with value of new array like this

i will be out put like this:

```
 Array
(
    [tool_situs] => Array
        (
            [template] =>aa
            [title] => ddd
        )

    [style] => Array
        (
            [.title] => Array
                (
                    [color] => #fff
                    [font-size] => 20px
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: *I Already Tried to use* ...? Tried to use what?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @TSaddamFahmiMoely  check [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

Comment: @ jitendrapurohitsorry thanks by using  array_replace_recursive not array_merge_recursive()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have stated you want to use `array_replace_recursive()` Something like the following should work:

`$updatedStyles = array_replace_recursive($currentStyles, $newStyles);`

This for me would output the following array:

```
Array
(
    [tool_situs] => Array
        (
            [template] => aa
            [title] => ddd
        )

    [style] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [color] => blue
                    [font-size] => 20px
                )

        )

)
```

Can find more information about the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) and you can find a working example [here](https://ideone.com/JgcLkR)

Comment: I 've been looking for this answer very long time, thanks you, next time i will more thoroughly  difference  array_replace_recursive and array_marge_recursive. thanks u

Answer (score 0):

[`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) is what you need.

```
$array1 = your_first_array();
$array2 = your_second_array();

$result = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);

var_dump($result); //result array is same as what you've shown as output in your question.
```